# Can't compile XeLaTeX with LaTeXTools for Sublime (OSX)

Tags: xetex, sublime-text, latextools

LaTeXTools works for me when I do regular LaTeX files. But whenever I try building my XeLaTeX file, I get this output:

```
[Compiling /some/path/to/file.tex]

SimpleBuilder: pdflatex run 1; done.

Errors:

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:43: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [ }]


[Done!]
```

And when I look inside the Sublime console, this is what is written:

```
<module 'simpleBuilder' from '/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/LaTeXTools/builders/simpleBuilder.py'>
<class 'simpleBuilder.SimpleBuilder'>
5
Welcome to thread Thread-167
['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', 'resume']
Finished normally
1
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the `simple` builder, which is fine for some situations, but its important to understand that the simple builder really is just that, a simple builder: it builds LaTeX documents using `pdflatex` and, if necessary, runs `bibtex` to generate a bibliography. That's it. Its actually intended as an *example* of how to write a builder than a fully featured builder itself and so there are a range of features that it does not and is unlikely to ever support.

Currently, the only mechanism LaTeXTools provides to build a XeLaTeX document is to use the `traditional` builder.

You can switch to by changing the `builder` option in your `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` file to `traditional` or `default` or even just leaving it blank. You can also tweak this in your project settings file, if you use Sublime Text projects.

Once you are using the `traditional` builder, you can tell LaTeXTools to use `xelatex` by either:

1. Adding a line like `%!TEX program = xelatex` to the beginning of your document.

or

2. In the `builder_settings` section of your `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` (or the `settings` section of your project file) create a `program` setting and set this to `xelatex`. It should look something like this:

   ```
   "builder_settings": 
   {
       "program": "xelatex"
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving both the solution and the explanation of what the problem was.