# SublimeText LaTeXTools traditional builder not recognizing XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, sublime-text

I have read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284718/cant-compile-xelatex-with-latextools-for-sublime-osx), but I am using the `traditional` builder in LaTeXTools, and I have

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
```

in the beginning of my .tex file, but the builder is still compiling my file with `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`, and I am getting the output

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking latexmk... done.
```

How could I force the builder to compile with `xelatex` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SublimeText you can select a different builder using the short cut `Ctrl-Shift-B`.

Comment: How do I make the builder respect `!TEX program`, though?

Answer (score 1):

I have been confused by this as well, but I think I finally solved the puzzle.

I finally found a discussion in the LaTeXTools docs under "[Selecting Build Variant](https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keybindings/#selecting-build-varianthttps://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keybindings/#selecting-build-variant)":

> Note: The settings provided by build variants override settings specified using TeX directives or in your settings. This means, for example, if you select a build variant that changes the program, %!TEX program directives or program settings will be ignored. If you want to return LaTeXTools back to its default behavior, please select the LaTeX build variant.

When I build using `LaTeX` (not `LaTeX - Traditional` or `LaTeX - PDFLaTeX`), then the `!TEX program` directive is indeed processed correctly. For example, if I have the following at the top of my `.tex` file:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
```

And I compile using `cmd`-`shift`-`b` (on a Mac) and then select `LaTeX`, Sublime indeed compiles using `XeLaTeX`. Once I set my build system to default to `LaTeX` (not `LaTeX - Traditional` or `LaTeX - PDFLaTeX`) under **Tools **>** Build With...**, then this works even with `cmd`-`b`.

There's a lot of confusion when searching for this problem.

- *Why does this matter?* In my typical workflow, I will multiple documents that each require a different builder (usually `PDFLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`). I'd like to use the `%!TeX` directives to specify this so that I can use a single shortcut `cmd`-`b` to compile, rather than using `cmd`-`shift`-`b` and then selecting the build program. It's a small thing that I end up doing over and over again, but it helps me stay focused on the writing rather than taking a split second to remind myself what type of document I'm compiling.
- *Why did this get complicated?* I think at some point I set `PDFLaTeX` to be my default build engine. This supersedes the `%!TeX` directive. There are lots of StackExchange responses elsewhere that say "just sue the directive" and are confused when that solution doesn't work for everyone. It may be that (like me) some didn't realize that changing default build engine setting would "break" the directives.

I hope that helps.